# How to resolve libgtksourceview-3.0-common (>= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy1) dependency?

Tags: 14.04

I have been trying to install gnome3 to my ubuntu. And a had a partial success. At some point of installation, I came to an error, which I don't have any luck of solving, and I have searched for hours. The installation of gnome3 is now not that much of an issue, but of solving a dependency problem.

The problem is this: Every time I run an e.g. `sudo apt-get install -f` I get an error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   libgtksourceview-3.0-1 : Depends: libgtksourceview-3.0-common (>=
>   3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy1) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu1 is installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

when I run a `apt-cache policy libgtk-3.0` I get:

```
libgtk-3-0-dbg:   Installed: (none)   Candidate:
3.10.7-0ubuntu1~saucy1   Version table:
     3.10.7-0ubuntu1~saucy1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     3.10.6-0ubuntu2~saucy1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     3.8.4-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages libgtk-3-0:   Installed: 3.10.7-0ubuntu1~saucy1   Candidate:
3.10.7-0ubuntu1~saucy1   Version table:  *** 3.10.7-0ubuntu1~saucy1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.10.6-0ubuntu2~saucy1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     3.8.4-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
```

I have tried removing libgtksourceview-3.0-common so I could install a new version, but I also get:

```
> sudo apt-get remove libgtksourceview-3.0-common

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 : Depends: libgtksourceview-3.0-common (>= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Does anybody have an idea how can I fix this dependency issue? This has happened on latest ubuntu 14.04 and also on earlier versions , like 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the GNOME3 PPAs (presumably added while you were using 13.10, and so still using the 13.10 tag). Update the PPA entries to use `trusty` instead of `saucy`, or [remove the PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/a/313/158442) altogether:

```
sudo sed -i 's/saucy/trusty/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Note that if you do choose to remove the PPA, you will have to use `ppa-purge`, considering the extent of the effect the GNOME PPAs have.

Comment: Yes, it does make sense, but just wondering, is it possible to remove the `3.8.2-0ubuntu1` as it seems that that is causing the problem as I have it still installed?

Comment: @Aleks The second error was about `libgtksourceview-3.0-1`. Try removing both together: `sudo apt-get remove libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtksourceview-3.0-1`.

Comment: Hmm, have tried that earlier, but now again with your command and I  am getting an error `gedit : Depends: libgtksourceview-3.0-1 (>= 3.10) but it is not going to be installed` :/

Comment: @Aleks looks too ingrained to me. You can try downloading the newer versions using the [Ubuntu packages index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&keywords=libgtksourceview-3.0) and installing them manually using `dpkg -i`.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me too. For the record if anybody runs to this post, after trying to install packages manually, I received an error `trying to overwrite '/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/julia.lang', which is also in package gedit-gmate 0.12~uorppa0`. Maybe if I solve it, maybe I will be able to solve other problems. I will post an update

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, even though the above commands didn't solve my problem, but it directed me to where the problem was and what was the problem - in PPA sources. Thanks